# Django date fields never evaluate equal when compared

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two instances of a model object, and I want to do something if they differ in one field, that happens to be a **DateField** but, when I evaluate wether they are different, they always are, even when they have the same date.

This is the code that performs the comparison:

```
for field in fields:
    if 'name' in field.__dict__:
        field_name = field.__dict__['name']

        if field_name in instance.__dict__:
            new_value = instance.__dict__[field_name]
            old_value = old_instance.__dict__[field_name]

            if new_value != old_value: # This line always avaluates true when fields are DateField
                print("{} - {}".format(old_value, new_value))
                if first:
                    first = None
                else:
                    detail = detail + '\n'

                    detail = detail + field_name + ' = ' + str(old_value) + ' --> ' + str(new_value)
```

I am printing `new_value` and `old_value` for debugging, and I find that date fields always evaluate different, even when they have the same date:

[image]

I don't know if there is an specific way for comparing date values.

Comment: I think you're comparing properties so the types are equal. Printing new_value won't show you this as it will print the representation of the object.

Comment: I found that instances of the same model have different type in the same field (one is datetime and the other string), but I don't know why it happens

Comment: Try `getattr` instead of accessing `__dict__`.